# Trying to remember a short story in which a woman can hear people talking while in coma

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember a short story. It was at the end of another fiction book as an extra. I read mostly books by Marian Keyes, Cecelia Ahern, L.J Smith etc so was probably at the end of one of those.

It was about a woman in a coma and she hears what people are saying. One of them is her partner who is saying he wants her to wake up etc... but she won't because he is the one that put her there. It's only a short story from what I can remember but didn't know if it's been turned into a full book.

Please can someone remember which book it was as I'm going crazy trying to think of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: What about this do you feel is science fiction or fantasy? This sounds like a standard modern thriller.

Comment: I have no idea why it was put into that category apologies. I'm new